# \cs_new:Npn vs \cs_new:Nn

Tags: expl3, latex3

I noticed that there are two different ways to define a new function in LaTeX3:  using *parameter text* or *siganature*.

For example, I can use both `\cs_new:Npn` and `\cs_new:Nn` to create a function `\mytest_foo:n`:

```
\cs_new:Npn \mytest_foo:n #1
  { some~ code~ containing~ #1 }
```

or

```
\cs_new:Nn \mytest_foo:n
  { some~ code~ containing~ #1 }
```

I only know that the second method will "detect the number of parameters automatically from the function signature". But what's the real difference between them? And how can I choose from these two `\cs_new:...`?

PS: Is it a bad convention to use both of them in one file?

Comment: `\cs_set:Npn` is essentiall nothing but `\long\def`, whereas `\cs_set:Nn` makes the argument from the signature.  It's a little like `\newcommand` where you only give a number.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, I'll note that the `:Nn` version is only useful for defining 'well-behaved' `expl3` functions: if we want `w`-type arguments or to define document commands (*inside* `xparse`), we have to use the `:Npn` version. Thus it is quite possible to favour `:Nn` but still use `:Npn` in some places.

With that restriction in place, the two are functionally equivalent: both versions in the question give an identical outcome. There are though two differences in use. The first is that the `:Nn` version has to work much harder than the `:Npn` one to extract the signature. If you do a trace, there is a lot of code to do it, so the `:Nn` version is slower. For most uses that isn't a big problem as they are being used a point-of-loading, and the actual time cost is small. However, if you are doing a definition at point of *use* (particularly in a 'tight' loop) then you'll want the`:Npn`.

The main difference is thus one of appearance/style, and the team have provided both as code authors will have different views on this. For some people, the fact that`:Npn` requires an explicit `#1`, *etc.* will be seen a good thing, whereas for others this will be seen as making the code less clear compared to the auto-detection of the `:Nn` version. There are arguments both ways here, and for this reason both versions are provided.

Comment: You'll see from my own code that I favour `:Npn` but that's just an opinion ...

Comment: ... whilst in contrast Will (for example) favours `:Nn`  (see `fontspec`).

Comment: One thing is that one cannot only use `:Nn` (if you have some strange things) but can only use `:Npn`. It reminds me of the "Holy War" between spaces and tabs...

Comment: Is `:n` required in the function's name when defining the function with `\cs_new:Npn`? it seems redundant to use both it and a parameter list.